# PostgreSQL: Improve system performance, KNN modification with GiST Index

Tags: performance, postgis, gist-index, nearest-neighbor, postgresql-performance

In my **PostgreSQL 9.5beta2**, **Postgis 2.2.0** compiled by Visual C++ build 1800, 64-bit I am running a Nearest-Neighbor-Query with the additional complication of unique assignment. I am running this on i5-3317U CPU @1,7GHz and 4GB RAM.

```
UPDATE pvanlagen p1
SET    buildid = sub.b_gid
     , dist    = sub.dist  -- actual distance
FROM  (
   SELECT DISTINCT ON (b_gid)
          pv_gid, b_gid, dist
   FROM  (
      SELECT gid AS pv_gid, ST_Transform(geom, 31467) AS geom31467
      FROM   pvanlagen
      WHERE  buildid IS NULL  -- not assigned yet
      ) p
        , LATERAL (
      SELECT b.gid AS b_gid
           , round(ST_Distance(p.geom31467
                         , ST_Transform(b.centroid, 31467))::numeric, 2) AS dist  -- see below
      FROM   buildings      b
      LEFT   JOIN pvanlagen p1 ON p1.buildid = b.gid  -- also not assigned ...
      WHERE  p1.buildid IS NULL                       -- ... yet  
      ORDER  BY p.geom31467 <-> ST_Transform(b.centroid, 31467)
      LIMIT  1
      ) b
   ORDER  BY b_gid, dist, pv_gid  -- tie breaker
   ) sub
WHERE   p1.gid = sub.pv_gid;
```

Details on the query on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34517386/unique-assignment-of-closest-points-between-two-tables/34521492?noredirect=1#comment57423039_34521492). I am already working with an spatial GiST Index.

```
CREATE INDEX build_centroid_gix ON buildings USING gist (ST_Transform(centroid, 31467));
```

I have to **repeat** the query, until all `pvanlagen.gid` are assigned. The query itself seems to be efficient, so that I concluded that the problem has to relate to my server configuration.

The effectiveness of the query follows a logarithmic curve. By now I have **261548 of 269019 assigned**, altogether with an execution time of ~76h.
First run 158376 rows affected, 02:40:7247 hours execution time. **Last but one run (16th run)** 984 rows affected, 06:12:21648 hours execution time.
Following the logarithmic curve, there is no finishing in sight.

I ran the last Repeat after a manual `SET work_mem='2000MB'` and 743 rows were affected within 03:52:10851 hours execution time. This is an improvement in the duration, but still not efficient.

I tested `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`for 100 Rows, where 37 rows were assigned (which is why I have to repeat the query again and again):

```
"Update on pvanlagen p1  (cost=555193.42..555201.96 rows=1 width=329) (actual time=333059.379..333059.379 rows=0 loops=1)"
"  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=555193.42..555201.96 rows=1 width=329) (actual time=333057.605..333058.210 rows=37 loops=1)"
"        ->  Subquery Scan on sub  (cost=555192.99..555193.50 rows=1 width=104) (actual time=333057.551..333057.618 rows=37 loops=1)"
"              ->  Unique  (cost=555192.99..555193.49 rows=1 width=40) (actual time=333057.529..333057.575 rows=37 loops=1)"
"                    ->  Sort  (cost=555192.99..555193.24 rows=100 width=40) (actual time=333057.527..333057.540 rows=100 loops=1)"
"                          Sort Key: b.gid, (round((st_distance((st_transform(pvanlagen.geom, 31467)), st_transform(b.centroid, 31467)))::numeric, 2)), pvanlagen.gid"
"                          Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 29kB"
"                          ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.41..555189.67 rows=100 width=40) (actual time=4100.470..333057.142 rows=100 loops=1)"
"                                ->  Limit  (cost=0.00..200.34 rows=100 width=36) (actual time=1.705..2.972 rows=100 loops=1)"
"                                      ->  Seq Scan on pvanlagen  (cost=0.00..20749.08 rows=10357 width=36) (actual time=1.703..2.953 rows=100 loops=1)"
"                                            Filter: (buildid IS NULL)"
"                                            Rows Removed by Filter: 625"
"                                ->  Limit  (cost=0.41..5549.86 rows=1 width=36) (actual time=3330.538..3330.538 rows=1 loops=100)"
"                                      ->  Nested Loop Anti Join  (cost=0.41..16411135680.91 rows=2957254 width=36) (actual time=3330.536..3330.536 rows=1 loops=100)"
"                                            Join Filter: (p1_1.buildid = b.gid)"
"                                            Rows Removed by Join Filter: 15714446"
"                                            ->  Index Scan using build_centroid_gix on buildings b  (cost=0.41..594040.19 rows=3226273 width=36) (actual time=0.292..3.760 rows=109 loops=100)"
"                                                  Order By: (st_transform(centroid, 31467) <-> (st_transform(pvanlagen.geom, 31467)))"
"                                            ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..23119.29 rows=269019 width=4) (actual time=0.011..15.920 rows=143604 loops=10943)"
"                                                  ->  Seq Scan on pvanlagen p1_1  (cost=0.00..20723.19 rows=269019 width=4) (actual time=0.004..215.509 rows=269019 loops=1)"
"        ->  Index Scan using pv_bis2010_bayern_wgs84_pkey on pvanlagen p1  (cost=0.42..8.44 rows=1 width=229) (actual time=0.011..0.011 rows=1 loops=37)"
"              Index Cond: (gid = sub.pv_gid)"
"Planning time: 4.141 ms"
"Execution time: 333067.649 ms"
```

Any idea on how to improve the efficiency is welcome!